# Nice parameterization of $x^2 + y^2 - kx^2y^2 =1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Can anyone find a nice simple parameterization of this curve. Just the quarter where $x \ge0$ and $y \ge0$ would be fine.

The parameterization should be "nice" in the sense that the first derivative vector should never be zero or infinite.

You can assume that $0<k<1$.

If it helps, the curve looks somewhat like an circle, but increasing the $k$ parameter makes the curve more square-ish, like a so-called [super-ellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse).

Parameterization using rational functions would be very nice, but trigonometric functions would be OK, too.

I've tried the obvious trick: take a line at angle $\theta$ and find its intersection with the curve. This gives a parameterization in terms of $\theta$, but it's a mess. I'm hoping for something simpler.

If it matters to you, this is not homework. This equation represents a part of an aircraft fuselage, and having a parametric representation for it would make certain applications easier. Like drawing it, for example.

Comment: Maybe x=$\cos x/k$ and y=$\sec x/k$ ?

Comment: Noe that $$ x^4 - k x^2 y^2 + y^4 = 1   $$ is similar and a little better behaved, for example rotation by $45^\circ$ gives you one of the same with a different $k$ value

Comment: Thanks. But the guy is in love with the equation I showed (for goofy reasons, probably), and I can't tell him how to design his aircraft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the best I could do, after a lot of algebraic fiddling around. Set
$$
w(t) = \frac{2}{1 + \sqrt{1 - k \sin^2 2t}}
$$
and then
$$
x(t) = \sqrt{w}\cos t \quad ; \quad y(t) = \sqrt{w}\sin t
$$
Not too bad, I guess. Maybe the trig functions could be replaced by rational functions, and the whole mess could be simplified ??

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, you just want the part with $0 \leq x,y \leq 1$. Then you could just solve a quadratic equation in either $x$ or $y$ and get something like
$$t \mapsto \left(t,\sqrt{\frac{t^2-1}{kt^2-1}}\right),\quad t \in [0,1].$$

Comment: You are correct. I guess I left something out of the question -- I don't want any nasty things like zero or infinite derivatives. Sorry to waste your time. I will fix the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll bump into *elliptic curves* instead of rational functions. Nonetheless this shows that,

$$x^2 + y^2 - k x^2 y^2 - 1 = 0\tag{1}$$

has an infinite number of rational solutions. Solving for $y$,

$$y =\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-kx^2}}\tag{2}$$

If for some constant $k$ there is rational $x,y$, then one can treat $(2)$ as an elliptic curve. For example, let $k=1/3$, then $(2)$ has solutions $x = 2,\;266/23,\dots$ *ad infinitum*.

Comment: Sorry, but you lost me. How is the parameterization question related to the number of rational points on the curve ??